# Put an image into a directory

Tags: php

I have a website where the users can upload an image.
However, before they upload one, on registering I want a standard image to be put in the directory. Almost a placeholder image.

How do I get about writing PHP that would take a copy of a file and put it into a different directory when a user reigsters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a single placeholder image, and use that in case there isn't an uploaded image from the user. Example:
`<php
$user_image = 'path/to/file.jpg';

if (file_exists($user_image)) {
  echo '<img src="'.$user_image.'" alt="" />';
} else {
  echo '<img src="path/to/placeholder.jpg" alt="" />';
}
?>`

Comment: This is what I was thinking, awesome. Cheers bud.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function. It can't get any easier than that.

```
copy("img/default.jpg", $directory.$userid.".jpg");
```